# Fill in dropdown from json table

Tags: json, angular, list, drop-down-menu

So ...i have url (say... http://localhost:8080/website/country) that I target to get this list:

What i want is to populate dropdown with list of county names so user can pick one. 
I also did dropdown in html

I am using Angular 2, i have service in which I set to get url from database

I'm sure that I have mistake, so need help :D Thanks

Edit: this is component, if could help

Comment: What is your actual problem ?

Comment: Won't work ...seems i have wrong code inside these lines or I just havent connected things in good way. So i post this for clarification and posible correction :D

Comment: i guess this plunker is what you need [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ywkAlWM4NimtNvhqx917?p=preview)

Comment: Don't post your code as images. What if someone would like to try your code or want to use snippets of your code in their answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

It seems that there is trouble in your component.

First of all, you have to trigger the request which will retrieve the countries and assign the response.
It will looks like following (note we assign the Observable):

```
@Component(...)
export class CompanyTemplatePopupComponent {

   countries;

   ngOnInit(){
      countries = this.companyService.getCountries(); 
      // or whichever method you need to retrieve the list of countries
   }

}
```

Then in your template (note the use of `async` pipe):

```
<option *ngFor="let country of countries | async" [value]="country.id"> {{ country.name }} </option>
```

Comment: Made change but I still don't get dropdown do populate. Could be something else also mistaken in code?

Comment: Could you provide the code of your component ? I think the part where you link your http response to your countries property could be the problem

Comment: i just set service component, so u can give it a look :)

Comment: What I would like to see is not the service, but how you use it in your component ;) Fact is, I would like to see how `countries` property used in the ngFor is beeing assigned ;)

Comment: Have a look, i replaced image :D

Comment: I now get error that is pointing on {{country.name}} ...TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

html code will be

```
<select #countriesSelect class=custom-dropdown">
    <option selected disabled>Select Country</option>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries: [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In ts code you have to getAllCountries() method in constructor or ngOnInit(). getAllCountries() is a method to fill the data of countries to dropdown list

```
getAllCountries() {
  this.getHttp().get(this.url)
  .map( (response) => { 
     this.countries = response;
     console.log(response);  // To check countries is coming or not!
   })
}
```

Comment: First check that getAllCountries() method is on constructor or ngOnInit and then check that your http response is coming or not !..